# Removing a relation from a ParseUser in Parse.com android

Tags: java, parse-platform, android

I am trying to remove a realtion from a ParseUser in Parse.com.
I tried to find in the internet how to do this but I came with no success.
Someone here can help me? or give ma clue? It just can't seem to wotk for me.

I tried the following code:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(final AbsListView listView,
        final int[] reverseSortedPositions) {

    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("username", values.get(position));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {

                if (objects.size() != 0) {
                    if (objects.get(0).getUsername() != null) {



                        final ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser
                                .getCurrentUser();
                        if (currentUser != null) {
                            {

                                final ParseObject friend = new ParseObject(
                                        "Friends");
                                friend.remove(values.get(position));

                                friend.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                                        ParseRelation relation = currentUser
                                                .getRelation("Friends");
                                        relation.remove(friend);
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Player Has Been
                                        Remove"+values.get(position),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        currentUser.saveInBackground();
                                    }
                                });
                });

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Player Has Been Added",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }

                        //dialog.hide();
                    }

                } 
            }
        });

        adapt.remove(values.get(position));
        adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


}
```

please, I need your help.
and sorry for my poor english

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseRelation.html

Comment: Yes, I use 'relation.remove(friend);' and it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying your code to this, my guess is setting the template to ParseObject is important for linking the relation to the user.

```
ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation = currentUser.getRelation("Friends");
relation.remove(friend);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Player Has Been Add2321434243ed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
currentUser.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: this is exactly what i tried to do. it didn't work :/

Comment: "ParseRelation relation" is different than "ParseRelation<ParseObject> relation"

Comment: if you did indeed make that change are you getting any errors? have you tried debugging it and checking the values before the query?

Comment: Yes, I did the changes that you said and i stll getting errors.
It is comes the correct toast and it is recieving the correct name from values.get(position). it just don't removing this relation from the user. I'm really don't know how to fix this.
Thank you for replaying!

Comment: You need to use relation.getQuery() to get the relation object you want to remove. Your friend object is just a newly created ParseObject and doesn't exist in the relation, so it makes sense you can't remove it.

Comment: Thank you Dave S!
I just changed all my code and use relation.getQuery() and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much you helped me a lot!